# Sonata route parameters renaming

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

is there a possible way to rename route parameters in sonata-admin bundle?
current admin route is like `entity/{id}/show`, would like to do `entity/{name}/show`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override [the `getIdParameter` method](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php#L1124) in your administration class:

```
public function getIdParameter()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

Comment: tried it, doesnt work that easy, looks like i need to override controller, admin & template to get it to work ? :/

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I haven't tried it myself, so at this point, you know more than I do.

Answer (score 0):

routes are configured from the `configureRoutes` method of your admin class.

Here is how i added a custom route for the 'send' action of my 'EmailAdmin':

```
 protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
 { 
    parent::configureRoutes($collection);
    $collection->add('send', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/send');
 }
```

The first parameter of `add()` is the name of the action and the second is the path of the route.

that way you can configure your custom routes and if you clear the collection or don't call `parent::configureRoutes` you can redefine all the default routes.

More detailed information from the sonata doc: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/routing.html

A work around to change the id parameter could be to overwrite `getIdParameter()` and find the way to customize the action in the CRUDController so that items are queried by name or even creating your own custom action and route so you have full control

At the end of the day entities are always queried by their (unique) id so if you want the name of the entity as the id parameter in the url you either need to make the name property the identifier of your entity (and make it unique of course) or use something like apache mod_rewrite to rewrite your urls

Hope that helps